# f.select - disabling option based on the first one selected in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form in which user can select two players from a list (two separate select fields). I managed to do it using options_for_select helper, but 
user shouldn’t be allowed to select the same player twice - it obviously can't be something like player1 vs player1. I was experimenting with ‘disabled’ option, but without success, because list of available users should change dynamically after selecting first user, which probably can't be done in Rails?

Comment: This may help: http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, with little details, hence my answer will be generic to cover the majority of cases.

You'll have to use JavaScript to hide the same options from the other list. Rails works server-side, therefore you should reload the page if you want Rails to re-render the list without the selected option. But this is a terrible user experience.

However, you should also perform a server-side check. Even if you add the JS in place, it will still be possible to send a crafted request where the players are the same. This is something that must ultimately be verified at server-side level, in your Rails controller or wherever you have the logic to handle the comparison.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so. I'm not familiar with JS yet (at least on this level),  so maybe I just perform check in the controller